# Version Control System for non-programmers

Tags: svn, version-control

I am a newbie in Subversion and in VCS. I work with non-programmers. I want a program which works with Subversion or another client-server VCS. The program should show me all projects on the server with version numbers, notes about the project and version, and have the ability to download projects locally. The program must also have a graphical interface.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like http://tortoisesvn.net/ would work fine (it has a gui and you can view all files / revisions on a repository).

Screenshots for clarity: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=tortoisesvn+screenshots&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=NU35TuTaJOW3iQf5iam0AQ&ved=0CE4QsAQ&biw=927&bih=781

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) also as [good integration tool](https://www.smartsvn.com/features/) may have interests + [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) as web server-side frontend ("all projects on server", "download locally" as archive)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have web-interface for subversion repositories, **[FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview)** and **[ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/)** tools could be handy. Its main feature is that they display repository and its structure in a comfortable way using web-interface. Another great tool with similar functionality is **[WebSVN](http://websvn.info)**, which has a great [demo](http://demo.websvn.info) illustrating its capabilities.

Only disadvantage is that all these tools require installation, it might be tricky for non-programmer. But once it's installed, you have it up and running smoothly.

Another case, as [michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692572/michael) had mentioned is [**TortoiseSVN**](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). It is pretty easy to install and use. Actually, programmers use it very very often because it allows not only viewing repository content, but also changing it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of designers I know work with engineers by using the Versions app for Mac (haven't used it myself):

http://versionsapp.com/

Answer (score -2):

take a look on what [github](http://github.com/) has to offer. git would be the VCS and [github](http://github.com/) the repository including the (server) GUI. it also supports the import of SVN repositories.

**note:** [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Management) can be overwhelming at first. regarding git, take a look at the help here http://help.github.com/

Comment: Doesn't appear to address the question. GIT is probably the last consideration if dealing with non-programmers.

Comment: no problem. I proposed git in combination with github based on the requirements of the question (3rd sentence)... github is especially easy to use for non programmers.

Comment: question has nothing to do with git. mentioning it not only impertinent, but also has a potential to misguide the person who asked the question.

Comment: user clearly asked "I want a program which works with Subversion or another client-server VCS." git and github are another client-server VCS (or SCM) combination. therefore my answer is no misguide, it shows an alternative which can be considered by the user. he has the choice.